# How can I make a confirm dialogue appear in the newly opened tab?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, window.open, confirm

I want to open a new tab (with an URL from an array).
This works so far.

But when the new page is loaded or when the new tab is opened i want a confirm dialogue on the newly opened tab.

I would be very happy if you could help me.
Thank you in advance. :)

Here´s the code I´m trying to change:

```
<script>
    var urlArray = [
      'http://google.com',
      'http://www.yahoo.com',
      'http://gmail.com'
    ],
    timeToCloseWindow = 3000;
    function work() {
        if(urlArray.length==0) return;
        var url = urlArray.shift();
        var openWindow = window.open(url);
        var answer = confirm("Do you like this website?")
        setTimeout(function () {
            openWindow.close();
            work();
        }, timeToCloseWindow);
    }
    work();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  This should open a window, wait 3 seconds, then ask if you like this website.  If you hit OK, nothing further will open, but if you answer cancel, the next website will open and the process repeats until the user hits OK once or cancels all available websites.

```
var urlArray = [
  'http://google.com',
  'http://www.yahoo.com',
  'http://gmail.com'
],
timeToCloseWindow = 3000;
function work() {
    if(urlArray.length==0) return;
    var url = urlArray.shift();
    var openWindow = window.open(url);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(!confirm("Do you like this website?")) {
            openWindow.close();
            work();
        }
    }, timeToCloseWindow);
}
work();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Neil. :)